# Error while updating Extjs 5.0.1 to 6.2.1 (com.sencha.exceptions.ExParse: Failed processing references for myApp/app/controller/Main.js

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I am getting error while updating Extjs 5.0.1 to 6.2.1 , i update my existing project to 6.2.1 but i am getting error

(com.sencha.exceptions.ExParse: Failed processing references for myApp/app/controller/Main.js

```
[ERR] 
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExParse: Failed processing references for /MyApp/app/controller/Main.js
[ERR]   at com.sencha.tools.compiler.sources.Insta
[ERR] nceConfigReferenceProcessor.processInstanceConfig(InstanceConfigReferenceProcessor.java:155)
[ERR] 
[ERR] Total time: 19 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/MyApp/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:380: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/MyApp/.sencha/app/init-impl.xml:384: com.sencha.exceptions.ExParse: Failed processing references for /MyApp/app/controller/Main.js
```

i am using CMD 6.2.1.29

can any one help me on this please

Main.js is here https://jsfiddle.net/akhilgopinath/bnvf39ck/

Comment: Can you paste contents of Main.js file.

Comment: its big file do you want me to paste that here ?

Comment: yes , plz give contents of this file /MyApp/app/controller/Main.js

Comment: @Tejas1991i updated main.js jsfiddle link

Comment: i fixed this issue thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my case I've fixed it replacing empty strings '' by one space strings ' ' in view.

Source: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?330729-6-2-modern-container-tooltip